# Cannot get code which works on JSFiddle to work offline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have found a JS Fiddle post (http://jsfiddle.net/luk3a/4cj7a5zx/) which codes almost exactly what I am trying to do. I have copied the code for my offline practices where I run the code locally in Safari, I have never used JQuery and can't get the code to function outside of the JS Fiddle environment. The aim is to take an input and compare it to an array which then says true or false as to whether the input appears in the array. The input box appears in safari but nothing happens when I click 'check'.

I have tried putting the script in a separate node.js file, also I have tried different CDN options for different versions of JQ as well as downloading the whole package to my machine and linking it with a file path.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"

  ></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

$(window).load(function(){

$(document).ready(function() {
  var names = ['vadim', 'thomas', 'tanya', 'timur', 'eve', 'kate', 'karen', 
'peter'];

  $('#check').click(function() {
    var name = $('#name').val();
    if (jQuery.inArray(name, names) != '-1') {
      alert(name + ' is in the array!');
    } else {
      alert(name + ' is NOT in the array...');
    }
  });
});

  </script>

</head>
<body>
    <input id="name" type="text">
<input id="check" type="button" value="Check">

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Nothing happens when I press 'Check'. I am not a coder I simply want to implement this in a Wix site for a simple project.

Comment: If you test it locally does the url in the browser have `http://` or `file:///` in the addressbar?

Comment: Remove the line `$(window).load(function(){`. You never closed the braces for it and thus have syntax error but it is not needed either. Note: Use browser dev tools console (F12) to check for errors thrown

Comment: jQuery 1.7.1 is extremely old.

Comment: To all who have explained about the useless line thanks, all is working now :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you have forget to close:

```
$(window).load(function(){
   //your code
});
```

For your Informations:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) { 
    // executes when HTML-Document is loaded and DOM is ready  
    console.log("page is loading now"); 
});

$(document).load(function(e) { 
    //when html page complete loaded
    console.log("completely loaded"); 
});
```

Comment: It is not needed so why would you want to close it and not just remove it

Comment: i believe he can use the both in the same time:

$(document).ready(function(e) { 
    // executes when HTML-Document is loaded and DOM is ready  
    console.log("page is loading now"); 
});

$(document).load(function(e) { 
    //when html page complete loaded
    console.log("completely loaded"); 
});

Comment: Makes absolutely no sense using both for the same code block. Also `.load()` is deprecated

Comment: i updated my answer to explain the differnece between $(window).load and $(document).load

Comment: Ok but you are documenting a deprecated method. Remember that answers here are not just for person asking but for future readers also

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  I have removed this line `$(window).load(function(){` . You have forgot to close the braces

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 </head>

<body>
    <input id="name" type="text">
    <input id="check" type="button" value="Check">
 <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function() {
  var names = ['vadim', 'thomas', 'tanya', 'timur', 'eve', 'kate', 'karen', 
'peter'];

  $('#check').click(function() {
    var name = $('#name').val();
    if (jQuery.inArray(name, names) != '-1') {
      alert(name + ' is in the array!');
    } else {
      alert(name + ' is NOT in the array...');
    }
  });
});

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```